# Where is the membership id?

Tags: civimember

Hi I am testing updating memberships via the front-end 'import memberships'tool. 
The [membership id] is required in order to do this. For the life of me I cannot find a way to get it out of Civi  (cannot go inot the db, need to stick to stick to the frontend interface for users).

It's not on screen, not available as a field on membership reports, not available to set up as a profile view...
[image]

We are on 4.6.12
Any tips appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to **Membership > Find Memberships** and perform a search.
2. Select **All XX records**
3. From the action menu select **Export members**
4. Choose **Select fields for export** and **Continue**

You can then choose to export the **membership ID**, **membership type**, **membership start date** (all of which are needed to update a membership) and contact ID or Display Name or whatever else you need to match the memberships in the database to your external list of memberships.